# POCO lib "MailMessage was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, email, smtp, poco-libraries

I'm using POCO lib to send emails. It gives me theses errors:

```
(_UInt16 port = 587;_) UInt16 Was not declared in this scope
(_MailMessage message;_) MailMessage Was not declared in this scope
```

Here is a part of my code:

```
#include <Poco/Net/MailMessage.h>
#include <Poco/Net/MailRecipient.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SMTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/NetException.h>

MailMessage message;

QString host = "smtp.gmail.com";
UInt16 port = 587;
QString user = "xxxxxxxx";
QString password = "111111111AbCd";
QString to = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
QString from = "xxxxxxxxxx";
QString subject = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

subject = MailMessage::encodeWord(subject, "UTF-8");
```

**EDIT:**

When using `Poco::Net::MailMessage` I get the following errors: [Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucvbx.png)

Comment: It would take hours to re write that since it's not possible to copy it (Don't Think so...)

Comment: You need to link to PocoNet library (PocoNetd in debug mode).